# CMAKE for android, how to include header files generated by subdirectory

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm building a project that has https://github.com/j0r1/JRTPLIB as a subdirectory because I need to build some things in it first before I build my project. I added a dependency based on

```
add_subdirectory(../third_party/JRTPLIB jrtplib)
add_library(myRtspClient SHARED ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(myRtspClient jrtplib-shared)
```

where `jrtplib-shared` is a target in `../third_party/JRTPLIB` `CMakeLists` file.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/j0r1/JRTPLIB/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L182), some header files are generated and placed in an unconventional place. This place in my project is

```
android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/jrtplib
```

where the `jrtplib` name comes from the line `add_subdirectory(../third_party/JRTPLIB jrtplib)`

*note that it also generates the files into* `android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x68/jrtplib`

I need to include the header files generated in `android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/jrtplib` or `android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86/jrtplib` into my project to finish the compilation.

I obviously tried `include_directories(jrtplib)` but it didn't work, files are not found.

So how am I supposed to include header files generated from a subdirectory?

**UPDATE:**

```
1 error generated.
  FAILED: /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DmyRtspClient_EXPORTS -I/home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/include -I/home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/../third_party/Base64_live555/include -I/home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/../third_party/md5/include -Ijrtplib/src -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystem /android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myRtspClient.dir/MediaSession.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/myRtspClient.dir/MediaSession.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myRtspClient.dir/MediaSession.cpp.o -c /home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/MediaSession.cpp
  In file included from /home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/MediaSession.cpp:17:
  /home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/include/myRtpSession.h:19:10: fatal error: 'rtpsession.h' file not found
  #include "rtpsession.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: The line you refers to creates (via `configure_file`) header file `rtptypes.h` under `src/` subdirectory. If your C code include this header via `#include <rtptypes.h>`, you need to include directory with that file, that is `<build-directory-for-jrtplib>/src`. I would also suggest to build `jrtplib` project with `ExternalProject_Add` command instead of `add_subdirectory`. So at the time your main library will be built, external project will have already be installed, and its headers (both initial and generated) will be already copied to the single directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev the add_subdirectory method ir preferable because that's what android page recommends https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake because there's no ExternalProject_Add in current android's cmake build. How do I include `<build-directory-for-jrtplib>/src`? I don't want to include the full path.

Comment: The second argument for `add_subdirectory` denotes build directory of the subproject. So you may refer to the include directory with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/jrtplib/src`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's the problem. It won't find the header if I do this way. In the output, it shows all the include paths. Here's what `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/jrtplib/src` produces: `-Ijrtplib/src` while other `include_directories` lines produces full paths

Comment: So CMake thinks that your library is built with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` as current directory, that is why it drop absolute part of the path. Could you show ([edit] your question) **exact error message** you have got? With command line which is executed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think the files are not being generated. It's trying to build my library first, not JRTPLIB. But there's an explicit `add_dependencies(myRtspClient jrtplib-shared)` and such target exists on `../third_party/JRTPLIB`

Comment: You library is built at *build stage*, but `configure_file` generates files at *configure stage* (when `CMakeLists.txt` scripts are proceed). There should be no problem in ordering.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hmm, that's right. However I cannot see any of the generated headers in my current folder

Comment: @Tsyvarev just updated with the exact error

Comment: @Tsyvarev my current CMakeLists https://github.com/lucaszanella/myRtspClient/blob/b38a6aac238ecbb829377c5812257eb4173249e2/myRtspClient/CMakeLists.txt (../third_party/JRTPLIB is ../third_party/jrtplib-3.9.1 in my folder )

Comment: The header `rtpsession.h` **isn't generated**, it initially exists under `src/` subdirectory of the subproject. So you need to refer to *source* (not *build*) directory: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third_party/JRTPLIB/src`. (Part `../third_party/JRTPLIB` is the first argument to corresponded `add_subdirectory()` call).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, it worked. Now it's cmplaining about undefined references to the other library like this: `/home/project/src/jscam/myRtspClient/myRtspClient/myRtpSession.cpp:38: error: undefined reference to 'jrtplib::RTPGetErrorString(int)'`. I didn't tell it to link to the other library. Why is it trying to link things?

Comment: @Tsyvarev in order to build my shared library libMyRtspClient.so do I need librtp.so?

Comment: As usual, when use a library, you need to link with it. As you include the library's project with `add_subdirectory`, it is better to link with the **library target**, created by the project. Most likely, the target is `jrtplib-shared` (created at [src/CMakeLists.txt:136](https://github.com/j0r1/JRTPLIB/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L136), so link command would be `target_link_libraries(myRtspClient jrtplib-shared)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, but is this linking only for verification or is librtp.so being included inside libmyrtspclient.so? I thought I only needed to link the library in the usage, not in the compilation.

Comment: The error "undefined reference" is a **linking error**, not a *compiling* one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but why linking is necessary? Why CMake tries to link things?

Comment: In short, linking stage adjusts "connections" between your library and a library, which functions you use. This is generic process when build a shared object (a library or an executable), there is no CMake-specific here. If you want to know more about linking, just google it.